# I am authenticating to azure through python to list down all my virtual machines and I am getting this error

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I am getting this error when I try to list down all my vms on Azure through python

```
Code: AuthorizationFailed
Message: The client "XXXX" with object id "XXXX" does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXX or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

my code is  below:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


Subscription_Id = "XXXX"
Tenant_Id = "XXXXX"
Client_Id = "XXXXX"
Secret = "XXXXX"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=Client_Id,
    client_secret=Secret,
    tenant_id=Tenant_Id
)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, Subscription_Id)
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
pageobject1 = vm_list.by_page(continuation_token=None)
for page in pageobject1:
    for j in page:
        print(j)
```

Comment: Based on the error message, looks like your Service principal doesnt have the required permissions. trying assigning the `Virtual Machine Contributor` permission to your SP.
run the python script & check whether you are able to list the virtual machines or not

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT this script is listing the virtual machine but this error occurs. also when I am authenticating the service principal and assigning role to my client ID is not shown in the search

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/n6kb9e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing your app registration `applicationId/objectId`   you need to pass the `service principal/appregistration name` when you are trying to assign a particular role like `virtualmachinecontributor` to your Service principal as show in below.

[image]

- Post providing the required access to the `service principal/appregistration`  you will be able to pull the list of virtual machines in your subscription. we have checked the above python in our local environment which is also working fine.

**Here is sample output screenshot for reference:**

[image]

---

**Updated Answer To pull list of VM's using Resource Management Client:**

```html
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


Subscription_Id = "<subId>"
Tenant_Id = "<tenantid>"
Client_Id = "<appId>"
Secret = "<clientSecret>"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=Client_Id,
    client_secret=Secret,
    tenant_id=Tenant_Id
)

resource_client=ResourceManagementClient(credential=credential,subscription_id=Subscription_Id)
resource_list=resource_client.resources.list()
for item in resource_list:
    if(item.type == 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'):
        print(item)
```

Comment: I am getting this error my libraires are upto date but still getting error please guide me `pageobject1 = vm_list.by_page(continuation_token=None)
AttributeError: 'VirtualMachinePaged' object has no attribute 'by_page'`

Comment: can you take a look into my updated answer & try using the resource management client to pull the list of vm's instead of using compute management client

Comment: the error changed  `self._creds.signed_session(session)
AttributeError: 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`

Comment: Have you tried the new python that i have shared in the above using resource management client ?

Comment: yes sir i have imported that library

Comment: can you join this chat room so that we can discuss further https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/240192/70366654